# How can I show revisions from tags/branches in the TortoiseSVN log window?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to show all of the revisions--specifically, revisions that are created when tags/branches are created--in the "show log" window?

I know that I can see a graphical representation of the tag/branch information from the "revision graph" window, but I'd like to know if I can see similar information in the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show the log for the repository root (usually one level above trunk/branches/tags) and you'll get all the log messages.

To do that, open the repository browser, right-click on the top node in the left tree view and select `show log` from the context menu.